# wget a https url generates 301 moved permanently error

Tags: curl, get, wget

I am trying to use curl to retrieve a usps.com url, but got 301 moved permanently error.
My code is in a file:

wget -O - "https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupResultsAction!input.action resultMode=1\&companyName=\&address1=123+main+street\&address2=\&city=east+brunswick\&state=MA\&urbanCode=\&postalCode=\&zip="

but the result is:
Resolving tools.usps.com (tools.usps.com)... 23.194.108.43, 2001:590:100c:18d::1bf2, 2001:590:100c:182::1bf2
Connecting to tools.usps.com (tools.usps.com)|23.194.108.43|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently

Tried all three: curl, GET and wget but to no avail.

Comment: Doesnt looks like valid URL. Try this https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupResultsAction!input.action?resultMode=2&companyName=&address1=&address2=&city=&state=Select&urbanCode=&postalCode=90001&zip=

Comment: no it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try some test client like posman, soapui?